# What would a "Plus Sign" marking be on aircraft fuselage?

Tags: aircraft-design

What is the plus sign found on some aircraft bodies?

The first time I saw this sign was on a Robinson R44 helicopter. The "plus sign" was located below the right front door.

Comment: got any pics? It's easier to know what you are talking about then.

Comment: Are you referring to a marking, something painted onto the aircraft? You don't mean something like [this photo](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://img.wp.scn.ru/camms/ar/40/pics/233_3.png&imgrefurl=http://wp.scn.ru/en/ww3/v/40/233/0&h=860&w=899&tbnid=gQbhNPhNFSSMWM:&docid=LPloPvHTNq6CuM&ei=UeSgVoDlF8HxjgTu2YagDA&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjA0eueiLvKAhXBuIMKHe6sAcQQMwguKBEwEQ&biw=1920&bih=955) do you?

Comment: If it's what @JonathanWalters was referring to, but much smaller, it probably marks the location of a first aid kit.

Comment: I agree with @FreeMan, its most likely a first aid kit, although after looking through probably 100 R44 pictures on Google images, I didn't see a single one with this mark.

Comment: Yes, a picture or, at least, more detailed description is needed for this to be answerable. At the moment it could be anything from a first aid kit to indicating that the aircraft is a medical evacuation aircraft to indicating that the aircraft flies for [Swissair](https://www.google.com/search?q=swissair&tbm=isch).

Comment: @peyman do you have a photo, or can you give a more detailed description of what you saw? This is a great question, but we need more information before it can be answered.